# visual studio/vs code typescript cannot find npm scoped module

Tags: typescript

In Visual Studio or VS Code, the statement `import Cycle from '@cycle/core';` in a TypeScript file gets underlined with red squigglies with the message: `Cannot find module @cycle/core`

Unfortunately TypeScript declarations don't exist yet for [Cycle.js](http://cycle.js.org/) (at least I couldn't find any).

So as an initial workaround I would like to create a `cycle\core.d.ts` file in my `typings` directory with an `any` type for the whole module. But I'm not sure how to declare it so that Visual Studio will be satisfied and enable to the project to be built.

The issue seems to be the `@` symbol in the NPM scoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
// cycle/core.d.ts
declare module '@cycle/core' {
  var whatever: any;
  export = whatever;
}
```

Comment: That approach worked. I was trying to use interfaces.